# Creating your own contour in opencv using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a set of boundary points of an object.

I want to draw it using opencv as contour.

I have no idea that how to convert my points to contour representation.

To the same contour representation which is obtained by following call

```
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(image,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By looking at the format of the **contours** I would think something like this should be sufficient:

```
contours = [numpy.array([[1,1],[10,50],[50,50]], dtype=numpy.int32) , numpy.array([[99,99],[99,60],[60,99]], dtype=numpy.int32)]
```

This small program gives an running example:

```
import numpy
import cv2

contours = [numpy.array([[1,1],[10,50],[50,50]], dtype=numpy.int32) , numpy.array([[99,99],[99,60],[60,99]], dtype=numpy.int32)]

drawing = numpy.zeros([100, 100],numpy.uint8)
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('output',drawing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Creating a contour this way works for cv2.drawContours but doesn't seem to work when using cv2.pointPolygonTest. Is there a way of actually returning a contour object ?

Answer (score 25):

To create your own contour from a python list of points L

```
L=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x5,y5],[x6,y6],[x7,y7],[x8,y8],[x9,y9],...[xn,yn]]
```

Create a numpy array **ctr** from L, reshape it and force its type

```
ctr = numpy.array(L).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(numpy.int32)
```

**ctr** is our new countour, let's draw it on an existing **image**

```
cv2.drawContours(image,[ctr],0,(255,255,255),1)
```

Comment: great answer, respecting all of opencv's constraints

Answer (score 13):

A contour is simply a curve joining all continuous points so to create your own contour, you can create a [`np.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with your `(x,y)` points in *clockwise order*

```
points = np.array([[25,25], [70,10], [150,50], [250,250], [100,350]])
```

That's it!

---

There are two methods to draw the contour onto an image depending on what you need:

**Contour outline**

If you only need the contour outline, use [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours)

```
cv2.drawContours(image,[points],0,(0,0,0),2)
```

[image]

**Filled contour**

To get a filled contour, you can either use [`cv2.fillPoly()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) or `cv2.drawContours()` with `thickness=-1`

```
cv2.fillPoly(image, [points], [0,0,0]) # OR
# cv2.drawContours(image,[points],0,(0,0,0),-1)
```

[image]

Full example code for completeness

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create blank white image
image = np.ones((400,400), dtype=np.uint8) * 255

# List of (x,y) points in clockwise order
points = np.array([[25,25], [70,10], [150,50], [250,250], [100,350]])

# Draw points onto image
cv2.drawContours(image,[points],0,(0,0,0),2)

# Fill points onto image
# cv2.fillPoly(image, [points], [0,0,0])

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: A contour has a more complicated shape than a  list of points, sadly

Answer (score 1):

To add to Cherif KAOUA's answer, I found I had to convert to list and zip my numpy array. Reading in an array of points from a text file:

```
  contour = []
  with open(array_of_points,'r') as f:
      next(f) // line one of my file gives the number of points
      for l in f:
          row = l.split()
          numbers = [int(n) for n in row]
          contour.append(numbers)

  ctr = np.array(contour).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
  ctr = ctr.tolist()
  ctr = zip(*[iter(ctr)]*len(contour))
```