# Extract selected region from image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-extraction

I have a region of an image selected, like this:

http://slideplayer.com/4593320/15/images/9/Intelligent+scissors+http%3A%2F%2Frivit.cs.byu.edu%2FEric%2FEric.html.jpg

and now, using OpenCV I would like to extract the region selected.

How could I do it? I have already researched but nothing useful got.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you "have it selected"? Please, elaborate...

Comment: I have the list of points that make the selected region .

Comment: In case you want to automatically select the region, the problem is called image segmentation. There are few deep learning techniques you can use to achieve this. 

https://www.kaggle.com/c/carvana-image-masking-challenge

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to import your pixel locations into the program and you have to create contour object using the points. I guess you know how to do this.

You can find from following link how to create contour object:

[Creating your own contour in opencv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161331/creating-your-own-contour-in-opencv-using-python)

You can fill black using following code out of your selected image

```
black = np.zeros(img.shape).astype(img.dtype)
color = [1, 1, 1]
cv2.fillPoly(black, contours, color)
new_img = img * black
```

I guess you know (or find) how to crop after black out remaining image using contour pixels.